# How do I create a moment date for the 31st day of a month?

Tags: momentjs

I am trying create a `moment` date for August 31, but there is some issue with the 31st of any month.

I am creating it like this `moment().date(31).month(7)`

which returns me Aug 1st.

When I use `moment().date(30).month(7)`, then I do get Aug 30th, like expected.

What do I do to create a `moment` date for the 31st?

Comment: Please read [the documentation for Moment](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/date/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation for the `.date` method](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/date/):

> Note: if you chain multiple actions to construct a date, you should start from a year, then a month, then a day etc. Otherwise you may get unexpected results, like when day=31 and current month has only 30 days (the same applies to native JavaScript Date manipulation), the returned date will be 1st of the following month.

To expand, the reason it gives you August 1st is because it first creates a date that is September 31 (which doesn't exist, so it goes to October 1st) and then the next chained call sets the month to August.